# Does Using both SSD & SATA Hard drive impacts Laptop Performance?

Tags: laptop, hard-disk

I'm planning to buy **New Precision 15 3561 Mobile Workstation**, it supports dual hard drives.

For drive one, I picked 1 TB SSD

[image]

and opted for 6 cell 97WHr battery

For 2nd additional drive, these are the below options I have

[image]

If I opt for **Additional 2.5" 2 TB 5400RPM SATA Hard Drive**, the battery 4 cells 64Whr battery should be selected.

I'm confused to pick the option here. Does Using both SSD & SATA Hard drive impacts Laptop Performance?

Can someone shed some light on choosing up the hard drives & battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I opt for Additional 2.5" 2 TB 5400RPM SATA Hard Drive, the battery 4 cells 64Whr battery should be selected.

This is probably because the larger battery takes up the space where a 2.5" HDD can be installed.

> Does Using both SSD & SATA Hard drive impacts Laptop Performance?

There is no surprise here, things that run on the SSD run at the SSD speed. Things that run on the HDD run at HDD speed. But since there's more stuff using power in the laptop the battery will be drained quicker. HDDs can conserve power by going to sleep if you make sure they're not being used in the background. If the HDD motor is running often, it will consume a little extra power and shorten the battery life.

> Can someone shed some light on choosing up the hard drives & battery?

It depends which matters more to you:

1. Is battery life the most important thing? -- Then get the 6 cell battery.
   You can always plug in a USB hard drive and get extra storage space that way.
2. Is tons of storage space without having to carry an external HDD important? -- Get the SATA HDD and "normal" battery. (4 cell batteries are typical)

Comment: What would you prefer battery life or Storage??

Comment: Depends on where and how I would use the laptop ;) I don't use laptops much, mine stays plugged in when I do use it at home and it's a big powerful laptop so battery life isn't good on it. When I was a student battery mattered a lot more and I would have liked a smaller laptop with good battery life.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt affect performance, as long as nothing is on the hard drive. If you actively use the hard drive, the app that uses the hard drive slows down to hard drive speed. For some tasks (like rendering a video), you can write to the hard drive without performance issues because the bottleneck is somewhere else (cpu)

Comment: They're asking about battery performance.